# Including image assets referenced in JSX in Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Is it possible to have Webpack include image assets in the build bundle without:

1. Using an import statement for that specific resource (which can be done with *Asset Modules* in Webpack 5)
2. Not writing it into a static HTML document as an src attribute (which can be done with *HtmlWebpackPlugin*)

I would have some React JSX code that reference image resources, either as a `src` attribute in an `<img>` element, or have some resource string, say `var imgUrl = './Assets/img.svg'`, and some element later using this string as an attribute.

Currently I could manually copy the entire `/Assets` folder into `/dist`, but I would have unused resources in `/Assets` and would like Webpack to figure out which ones are actually used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, now I understand, and unfortunately, this is not possible.
`React` won't detect the value of the `src` of the image because it will consider it just a `string`, and not a path. It won't figure out which file are you talking about. The only way to use it the way you want to do it is by having those images in the `public` folder, which you said you didn't want to do.

In my personal opinion what I usually do with static images if the app is small, is putting them all together in a file by importing them and exporting an object with all of them together. Finally every time I want to use any image I just import that file and use whichever image I want. With this approach, at the end of the day, I'll end up with just one file (bundle). It's just an approach, there are many different ways to do this but it's relative to the case

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be a stretch for Webpack / any plugin to parse all the strings and identify image file extensions. The situation I had is I downloaded an icon pack, but I'm not using all the icons, so didn't want to bundle unused resources. Looks like I'll just have to register which ones I'm going to use somewhere. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but maybe you could require the asset inline like this...

```
<img src={require('./Assets/img.svg')} />
```

If this is not what you are looking for, maybe you can explain me more in detail... I've quite a lot of experience playing with webpack, I think I may have a solution for you

Comment: Hi, no not quite like that. I'd rather be able to keep code as is with `<img src='./Assets/img.svg' />`. Your solution would be more along the lines of my point 1.